# converting .ppt files to .pdf with pdfnet/pdftron on windows 8.1 store app

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, pdftron, pdfnet

Im trying to do a file conversion using [PDFTron](https://www.pdftron.com)

I have something that looks like this:

```
 try
 {
    docpdf = new pdftron.PDF.PDFDoc();
    string fullpath = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path +"\\"+ Constants.DataDirectory + "\\" + document.GetFullPath().Replace("/", "\\");

    pdftron.PDF.Convert.ToPdf(docpdf, fullpath);
    StorageFile fileConverted = await currentFolder.CreateFileAsync(docpdf.GetDocInfo().GetTitle(), CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
    await docpdf.SaveToNewLocationAsync(fileConverted, pdftron.SDF.SDFDocSaveOptions.e_linearized);

    MyPDFViewCtrl.SetDoc(docpdf);
    MyPDFViewCtrl.SetPageViewMode(pdftron.PDF.PDFViewCtrlPageViewMode.e_fit_width);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
   Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
```

But i get a exception on the Convert.ToPdf line

> The text associated with this error code could not be found.
>
> Exception:     Message: An error occurred while converting the file.
>   Detailed error:   ToPDF cannot convert this file format on this
>   platform.      Conditional expression: false   Filename   : Convert.cpp
>   Function   : trn::PDF::Convert::ToPdf      Linenumber : 1825

Is it not possible on windows 8 store apps?

Answer (score 1):

Conversion of PPT to PDF is not built-in to PDFNet SDK for Windows Store Apps. Conversion of these file types is supported on PDFNet SDK for Windows (desktop/server, the PDFNet SDK variants downloadable from https://www.pdftron.com/pdfnet/downloads.html) using Office Interop. What some of PDFNet users will do is send those documents to a server of theirs, convert them to PDF on that server, then send them back to the device.

We also just released [direct DOCX to PDF](http://blog.pdftron.com/2015/09/08/convert-word-to-pdf/) conversion available on all platforms PDFNet is available on, including Windows Universal. PPTX support is coming in a few months.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```cs
pdftron.PDF.Convert.OfficeToPDF(
  docExcel, 
  appdirectory + @"\" + filenameExcel, 
  new pdftron.PDF.ConversionOptions()
);
```

Comment: Hi there, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Thank you for your contribution. It may be valuable to expand on your answer with a brief explanation of why this addresses the original problem.